# Trying to upload a file to a nodejs web service

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a simple web service in nodejs that accepts a file and saves it.
Here is my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var sys = require('sys');
app.listen(8080);

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
    var fileKey = Object.keys(req.files)[0];
    var file = req.files[fileKey];
    fs.readFile(file.path, function(err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(__dirname, data, function(err) {
            res.redirect("back");
        });
    });
});
```

I'm using fiddler to upload the file.

```
console.log(req.files);
```

gives undefined. An exception is also thrown:

```
Object.keys called on non-object
```

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do there for `fileKey` -- Also, when your write the file, you need to specify a file name as well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078074/nodejs-iterate-over-req-files-properties for fileKey

Comment: What is the name of the form control you're pulling this from?

Comment: There is no front end. I'm using fiddler to make the post. This is intended to be a webservice that will be called my a client application.

Comment: Well, seems the `req` object is never receiving any `files` -- so that is the underlying cause of the issue.

Comment: The request body in fiddler is:
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myTextFile"; filename="raw.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Comment: Add `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be using the [`bodyParser`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser) middleware which is required to parse uploads (amongst other things):

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/upload', function(req, res) { ... });
```